# Multiple Line Editview in layout XML

Tags: android

I want to create a multiple line editview to enter in some notes. I want the text aligned top left and 4 rows.  How do I create that in layout xml file.  Assume I am using a linearview.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1):

Use [`EditText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html).

Set `android:lines="4"`.

Set `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`.

Set `android:gravity="top|left"`.

Set other attributes (e.g., `android:id`) as needed.

Bake at 350 degrees Fahrenheit for 23 minutes or until toothpick inserted in center comes out clean. :-)